# Iterating through a list and using it to initialize another variable

Tags: flutter, dart

Sorry in advance since I am quite new to Flutter. I have a variable as shown below:

```
var points = <LatLng>[
    new LatLng(35.22, -101.83),
    new LatLng(32.77, -96.79),
    new LatLng(29.76, -95.36),
    new LatLng(29.42, -98.49),
    new LatLng(35.22, -101.83),
  ];
```

And I have a list of 10000 objects as shown below:

```
[
  [712587.3450605758, 1222487.8048128784], 
  [712605.1304073846, 1222422.3607431017], 
  [712633.6284776889, 1222314.3680556398], 
  [712671.8758878317, 1222172.6276533436], 
  [712682.3751768898, 1222133.630293984],
  // and more...
]
```

How would i incorporating this in the previous points variable so that i don't have to type it 10000 times????

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can iterate with a simple `forEach` loop on your second list and add elements to your first:

```
secondList.forEach((element) => points.add(LatLng(element[0], element[1]));
```